# DateTime ParseExact throwing exception with hh vs HH

Tags: c#, asp.net, ebay-api

`contacthours.Hours1From` and `contacthours.Hours1To` are throwing an exception. is there a difference between hh and HH ?

```
ExtendedContactDetailsType contactdetails = new ExtendedContactDetailsType();
contactdetails.ClassifiedAdContactByEmailEnabled = true;
ContactHoursDetailsType contacthours = new ContactHoursDetailsType();
contacthours.Hours1AnyTime = false;
contacthours.Hours1Days = DaysCodeType.Weekdays;
contacthours.Hours1From = DateTime.ParseExact("08:00", "hh:mm", null);
contacthours.Hours1To = DateTime.ParseExact("16:00", "hh:mm", null);
contacthours.TimeZoneID = "Eastern";
contactdetails.ContactHoursDetails = contacthours;

item.ExtendedSellerContactDetails = contactdetails;
```

Comment: what you mean "not working properly" what is the problem you are facing ? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: We can't guess what "not working" means.

Comment: Simple solution - use the debugger, step into your code and examine the values for `contacthours.Hours1From` and `contacthours.Hours2From` and make sure they're parsable as `DateTime`.  It'll most likely be quicker than waiting for someone to grab their SO crystal ball.....

Comment: At least one problem could come from the fact that you are using 24hr date time `16:00` which should be parsed as `HH:mm`.

Comment: I fixed the HH:mm but not working.. so I am using eBay APi obviously and I am able to post normally, however when I add this code nothing is happening.

Comment: per eBay: Hours1From ( time ) [0..1] 


Not used by any call.

 Indicates the starting time of day this eBay user is available for other eBay members to contact for the range of days specified using Hours1Days. Enter times in 30 minute increments from the top of the hour. That is, enter values either on the hour (:00) or 30 minutes past the hour (:30). Other values will be will be rounded down to the next closest 30 minute increment. Times entered should be local to the value provided for TimeZoneID.

Comment: @markkordahi, you should take a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you ask better questions. And why is a question consisting on "This somehow doesn't work" plus 10 lines of code upvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *first* problem is that you're not using the 24-hr hour format string:

```
contacthours.Hours1From = DateTime.ParseExact("08:00", "HH:mm", null);
contacthours.Hours1To = DateTime.ParseExact("16:00", "HH:mm", null);
```

Whether or not that's the *only* problem is unclear.

Comment: per ebay this is the get fonction: private System.DateTime mHours1From;[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time")]
        public System.DateTime Hours1From {
            get {
                return this.mHours1From;
            }
            set {
                this.mHours1From = value;
                this.mHours1FromSpecified = true;
            }
        }    so should I really use parseexact ??

Comment: I'm confused - are you _getting_ a time form the API or _sending_ one?  Are you _really_ hard-coding the times or do they come from the API?

Comment: no I am sending the time with this, I was trying to show you the source code for the setter function of Hours1From to make sure if it is appropriate to set it using my parseexact function..

Comment: Well from the standpoint that it takes a `DateTime` then yes.  It's not clear what the API does with the _date_ portion of the `DateTime`, though.

Comment: yes this is the problem I'm trying to explain.. i am not sure if the format i'm sending is correct..

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't _have_ a format - it's a binary representation of a point in time.  So whatever format you use _before_ you parse is irrelevant.

Comment: it looks like the allowed format is called GregorianCalendar

Comment: That's not a format - it's a representation of a particular date in years, months, and days.